# using X11 to ssh to a Linux server with a GUI application (such as i3) using XQuartz

Tags: ssh, x11, i3

I'm trying to ssh to a linux server and run GUI applications like i3. My personal computer is a MacOS Mojave and I have setup X11:

I setup XQuartz locally, `ForwardX11 yes` in my local ssh config and setup `X11Forwarding yes` in my server sshd config. I've installed `xorg`, `xinit` and `i3` on my server and connected to it using XQuartz on my local PC.

However when I run the command xstart in my XQuartz terminal, there is only text output and no GUI visible (see image). I've tried it on clean Ubuntu and Debian installs and I got the same results twice, so there's definitely something I'm doing wrong.

[image: startx text output]

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/70524). Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: In general, it should just work transparently when you either enable `ForwardX11 yes` or do `ssh -X ...`, no need to "setup Xquartz", or startx. What happens when you do that? Is there an error? Which one?

Comment: After it's installed `ssh -Y username@server` and the run an X11 app such as `xeyes` or `xclock`. You can get these by installing them via `apt-get install x11-apps`. If it's working, you'll see the eyes or clock appear depending on which app.